# ASP.NET Equivalent of history.back

Tags: c#, asp.net, browser-history

Does ASP.NET provide any way of interacting with the browser history ? My current way is to trigger it trough a

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript
```

Which still renders the entire page and flashes it to the user. Apart from using Response.Redirect is there any other way to go back ?

Comment: No it does not. Aspnet is server side. The history is client side. The only thing you can do is a javascript `history.back()`

Comment: Nope. ASP.NET is server side, by the time it gets to the browser it's all HTML, CSS and JavaScript.

Comment: All you can do is inject JavaScript into the page which could interact with the browser. Your server doesn't even know that it's definitely a browser which is requesting the page, it could be another application or service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the comments and my own discovery, ASP.NET can't interact with the browser history in anyway.

The best way would be to call a JS script trough the code behind:

ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "goBackJS", " window.history.back();",true);